# How to remove AJAX from jQuery validation plugin function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This is going to be a stupid question but I have spent an inordinate amount of time trying to remove the AJAX part from the jQuery validation plugin function below but still have the validation work. Suffice to say I haven't succeeded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myform").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules: {
        group: {required: true}, 
    },
    messages: {
        group: {required: " Choose a group."},
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#results').html('Loading...');
        $.post('', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
    }
});
});
```

So yeah, I'm dumb. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it, is it because you wish to redirect them to another page?

Comment: I've been using the function throughout my site as it's been perfect. But now I'm in a situation where I actually just want it to follow the "action='mynewpage.php'" in the form HTML. But I want to keep the validation.

Comment: @AzzyDude My recommendation will be in the form of a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send the object back, send it as a JSON object.

Here's an example where we're going to use the serialized elements, conditionalize some data, and then send something back with our new page.

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  if(isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($phone)){
    return json_encode(array('filled' => 'yes', 'loc' => 'newpage.php'));
  }

?>
```

Then in the validator, we can parse `data.loc` to the `window.location` to mimic the redirect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules: {
      group: {required: true}, 
    },
    messages: {
      group: {required: " Choose a group."},
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $('#results').html('Loading...');
      $.post('', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
        if(data.filled == 'yes'){
          window.location = data.loc;
        }

      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with JSON. I'm just trying to access what the user enters into the form using the POST method (e.g. $_POST['example']) in PHP?

Comment: When you send the `$('#myform').serialize()` over, you don't have to do anything special. If you have fields named things like -> `field_1, field_2, field_3`, you simply access them in php with the same name, `$_POST['field_1'], $_POST['field_2'], $_POST['field_3']` you don't have to do anything tricky there. Just when you output any data, make it into a JSON object so that we can access it like I said above.

Comment: @AzzyDude you'll see I've created the conditional check in the php file, sent the data back as an object, it has two properties, `filled` and `loc`. When we access the `data` object in the `function(data)` of the post, it uses intelligent parsing to understand that it's JSON we're working with. ow we can use `data.filled` and `data.loc` to get the values of the keys `filled` and `loc` that we made in our PHP file.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Man, I thought this problem would be a simple matter of replacing one line of my code...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the `submitHandler` function!

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#results').html('Loading...');
    // $.post('', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
    //     $('#results').html(data);
    // });
}
```

And after calling `.validate()`, call the `.valid()` function on `#myform` this way:

```
$('#myform').valid();
```

Just make sure you are removing the default action of submit on the form by adding this:

```
<form onsubmit="if (!$(this).valid()) return false;">
```

**Explanation:** This doesn't submit the `form` when it is not valid and shows the errors. If the form is valid, this function submits as a normal form submit.

But why do you wanna do that? What else you wanna do?

Comment: I just want it to go to the next page like it normally would. I'm just trying to avoid writing new validation for the form.

Comment: Yeah, thats what this script does. See the explanation. Hope it helps... :)

Comment: Hmm, I did what you asked but the validation seems to have stopped working. Can you just copy and paste the entire function in case I put something in the wrong place?

Comment: Which validation plugin are you using? I am using `jQuery.validate`. Okay, can you make a fiddle of what you have now? I will update it and add it in the answer. The concept is simple. If form is valid, submit. If not, show the errors! :)

Comment: OKay, gimme a few mins. If it is able for you to give your HTML in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it will be awesome. Shall I wait?

Comment: Here is the fiddle of what I have so far with your changes (I probably changed it wrong). http://jsfiddle.net/AzzyDude/DUjPa/

Comment: You forgot to add `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js` in your fiddle. :P

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but what about the rest? Did I edit it okay? Because it's not working in my document.